# mysql syntax to update record

Tags: mysql

What is the mysql query syntax to update an existing record

Comment: Please do not ask questions of this level. It's like "how do I add two numbers". Read the manual, a tutorial, or search. It definitely is not a new question you need to ask others to answer.

Comment: @Dan: regardless of the simplicity level for this question, it is covered as valid in the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: @Chris, such questions are discouraged: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/

Comment: am sorry... actually I shouldn't do this....

Comment: @Dour High Arch: Well, that kind of settles it. ;)  They should roll that info into the faq.

Comment: Given the cryptic nature of the MySQL documentation, I see no point in down voting this question. +1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Should be the same as other SQL syntax, no?

```
UPDATE TableName SET FieldName = Value WHERE Id = AnotherValue
```

And where does C# code come into this?  Exactly how are you accessing the database?

Answer (score 2):

It is all right here:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html.
Just wondering why you didn't [google](http://tinyurl.com/65nvn48) your question first.